# How does Regex engine work with (?=^.) and ^(?=.)?

Tags: .net, regex

What is the difference between these two Regex criteria:

```
(?=^.{3}).*
^(?=.{3}).*
```

Anchor ^ before lookahead and inside lookahead

Comment: Which is your regex engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference.  The anchor inside a lookahead group is treated like it were **outside** it.