# In Regex, what is the difference between (?!^)\G and \G(?!^)?

Tags: .net, regex

Given these two Regex:

```
(?!^)\G
```

and

```
\G(?!^)
```

What's the difference between negative lookahead after and before `\G` anchor?

Comment: I don't get this question. `\G` and negative lookahead are completely orthogonal. Each one does what it is supposed to do regardless of the presence of the other.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are posting such [non-practical questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337531/how-regex-engine-work-with-and)? Can I expect a third one like `\K(?=.*\d)foo` vs `(?=.*\d)\Kfoo`?

Comment: For those who are interested, here's a [pcretest dump](http://pastebin.com/MasJA6uK), note that it **might be different** with .net. I suspect that the chance would be very small...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, they come out to be the same thing. They are functionally equivalent. The `(?!^)` and the `\G` check two different conditions *at the same location in the string*, so it makes no logical difference what order the conditions are checked in.

The conditions are:

- `(?!^)` = “we are not at the beginning of the input string”
- `\G` = “we are in the location where the previous match ended”

However, in terms of performance, I suspect (though I haven’t tested) that the latter is faster. I would expect the regular expression engine to have an optimisation so that a regex that starts with `\G` would only be executed from the previous match’s end onwards, while the other one would go through the whole string “looking for” the location of the previous match.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same, since we are going to check **completely orthogonal** logical conditions.  Indeed, **in both examples** the negative lookahead

```
(?!^)
```

is combined with the anchor

```
\G
```

Hence, we are asking for something which **at the same time** is

- at the end of the previous match or at the start of the string for the
  first match
- not followed by anything which is at the start of the string.

Comment: `^` does not check for characters. It checks for the beginning of the string. Of course `(?!^)` can fail to match. It means (the equivalent of) “we are not at the beginning of the string”.

Comment: Nope, it means “what follows us cannot be at the beginning of the string”.

Comment: That is logically the same as what I said :)

Comment: `(?!^)abc` [won't match](http://regex101.com/r/kR6bD0) the first `abc` in `abcabc`

Comment: I’m going to take a stab in the dark here and suspect and that you downvoted my answer out of spite. Please do not do this. Only downvote answers that are wrong.

Comment: @RobertoReale: Robin is responding to your claim that `(?!^)` “always matches”.

Comment: @RobertoReale: I don't see any `\G` in your answer either: I'm commenting your post, not answering OP's question

Comment: My answer was in the context of the **original** problem, I suppose... may be I should clarify it?

Comment: @RobertoReale: as it stands, it seems you're saying "`(?!^)` always matches", whatever the context (which isn't correct). If you mean something else I think it needs clarification

Comment: Ok, I'll try and clarify it.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Perhaps I should point out that even after `\G`, it is still not the case that `(?!^)` always matches.

Comment: Can you please provide a counterexample?  Should I be wrong, no problem in acknowledging.

Comment: By default, `\G` matches at the beginning of the string. `(?!^)\G` is generally used to force `\G` to match only after a *real* match. `d|(?!^)\Gabc` will match consecutive `abc`s and `d`s after an initial `d`, `d|\Gabc` will match the same **and** a string starting with `abc` on top of that. See the difference when you [play around](http://regex101.com/r/hE4xD6).

Comment: You are right, but, once again, `d|(?!^)\Gabc` is NOT the regex the OP made reference to...  However, I tried to clarify my answer a little bit.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the meaning of `^` also depends on whether Multiline mode is in force... :)

Comment: If `(?!^)` always matches in this situation, how can `(?!^)\Gabc` and `\Gabc` return different answers? (one doesn't match `abc`, the other does)

Comment: @Robin  The regex I was referencing to is either `(?!^)\G` or `\G(?!^)` (as per the original question).  While you are surely right with regard to `(?!^)\Gabc` and `\Gabc`, they are entirely new regexes.

Comment: Since you didn’t respond to my comment about the downvote out of spite, I’m going to assume that it was you. In the future I will not explain myself anymore if this is what I get in return.

Comment: The `(?!^)\G` part works in the exact same way in the three examples, I added `abc` to make the fact that it matches more visible. You asked for a counterexample, this is one. If it convinces you more you can try and see that `\G` will return a match on any string and `(?!^)\G` on no string ([here](http://regex101.com/r/hJ7hZ0) for example, or with a short script)

Comment: @Timwi  I am not sure that I am following you here.  I didn't downvote your answer, but should that make you happy you can of course assume I did.  But that's not the point.  I don't think SO should be the place for anything but constructive dialogue.

Comment: @Robin  The question is not about `(?!^)\G` and `\G`, but about `(?!^)\G` and `\G(?!^)`.  And it's not difficult to check that none of thm matches.

Comment: Your answer explicitly stated that `(?!^)` would always match. Which isn't true, even next to `\G`. You asked for a counter-example. I just reread the thread, am I missing something?

Comment: Timwi stated that "even after `\G`, it is still not the case that `(?!^)` always matches".  Then I asked a counterexample, i.e. a string against which the `(?!^)` in `\G(?!^)` does not match.  Maybe I was not clear enough, again...

Comment: This comment thread has extended way too far already, but we may need to clarify what you mean by "`(?!^)` matches" then? Applied to `bar`, the regex engine starts by trying to match from before the `b`, at `|bar`. `(?!^)` fails the match. It then tries before the `a`, `b|ar`, the `\G` fails. Same for `ba|r` and `bar|`, where `\G` fails (but `(?!^)` would match ie return 'true', it's just not actually checked since regex has already failed)